# How to show names of selected nodes in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

Not sure where to ask, but found answers on cytoscape before, so here is the question.

I have a larger network in Cytoscape, about 1000 nodes. I want to show the whole net work with the names of a few nodes. I tried Annotation, but it is not editable after putting there (text or location).

Is there a way I can do something like this and keep other nodes clear, Programmatically or not?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sure!  You can select the nodes and then do a bypass to change the size, color, and label of the nodes.

Comment: The problem is when I zoom out, all labels are not shown, when I zoom in, all labels shown (with different sizes). When exported as image, all labels shown. I guess I have to map all none selected nodes to a NULL label. But it is not convenient if I want to know the names afterwards.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused.  The fact that the labels show up when you zoom in is normal -- that's a level-of-detail feature that improves performance for dense networks.  You can disable that by doing View->Show Graphics Details.  But if I understand you correctly, you want to be able to export the network without labels for all nodes, but still show those labels interactively.  Is that right?  If so, you are correct, there is no way to do that.  You can easily disable the labels by removing the node Label mapping (your bypass labels would still show).

Comment: Another thought.  If you want to be able to still see the node names, you could create a tooltip passthrough mapping.  At least then you can hover over the nodes and see the node name.